# Error in polylongdiv while using spanish babel

Tags: errors, babel, overleaf, polynom

I'm using `polylongdiv` from polynom `package`. When I use the option `style=D` I get

> Runaway argument?
>
> ! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of
> \language@active@arg~.
> \par  l.8 \polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5}{x^3+2x^2+9x+8}
> I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop.
> I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious, you'd better type
> `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

I'm using Overleaf, and here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5}{x^3+2x^2+9x+8}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do `\usepackage[spanish,es-notllde]{babel}`; nowadays you can directly type `ñ` and `Ñ`, so the shorthands `~n` and `~N` are no longer needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `es-notilde` option to `babel` for nowadays the shorthands `~n` and `~N` are no longer needed, since you can directly type in `ñ` and `Ñ`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish,es-notilde]{babel}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5}{x^3+2x^2+9x+8}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, patch the relevant macro in `polynom.sty` that uses `~` (for no apparent reason) to replace it with `\`  (backslash-space):

```
documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd*{\pld@ArrangeResult}{\~}{\c{nobreakspace}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5}{x^3+2x^2+9x+8}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same in both cases.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `\shorthandoff*{~}` in a group before the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

{\shorthandoff*{~}
\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^5}{x^3+2x^2+9x+8}}

\end{document}
```

[image]